# Java - Class not found error with Ant, Ivy

Tags: java, ant, ivy

I am new in ivy. I try to add some libs to my project with ivy.xml file to exclude jar files from the project.

I try now to build the simplest sample project where all staff I brought to a minimum.

Everything is working till I use the class from .jar library.
Ivy successfully retrieves libraries from ivy.xml but, even more, the
import for that class also works. But when I run ant it gives the following error.

NoClassDefFoundError

[image]

build.xml

```
<project default="run" xmlns:ivy="antlib:org.apache.ivy.ant">
<path id="default.classpath">
    <fileset dir="lib">
        <include name="**./*.jar" />
        <include name="*.jar" />
    </fileset>
</path>

<target name="clean">
    <delete dir="build"/>
</target>

<target name="resolve" depends="clean">
    <ivy:resolve />
    <ivy:cachepath pathid="default.classpath" />
    <ivy:retrieve sync="true" type="jar"/>
</target>

<target name="compile" depends="resolve">
    <mkdir dir="build/classes"/>
    <javac srcdir="src" destdir="build/classes" includeantruntime="true">
        <classpath>
           <path refid="default.classpath" />
        </classpath>
    </javac>
</target>

<target name="jar" depends="compile">
    <mkdir dir="build/jar"/>
    <jar destfile="build/jar/HelloWorld.jar" basedir="build/classes">
        <manifest>
            <attribute name="Main-Class" value="abc.HelloWorld"/>
        </manifest>
    </jar>
</target>

<target name="run" depends="jar">
    <java jar="build/jar/HelloWorld.jar" fork="true">
        <classpath>
            <path refid="default.classpath" />
            <path location="lib/*.jar" />
        </classpath>
    </java>
</target>
```

Comment: You're missing a Commons Lang dependency. Put the jar in the classpath. Be aware that Commons libraries are often dependent on other Commons libraries

Answer (score -1):

The last target should be changed to the following. Now everything works

```html
     <target name="run" depends="jar">
       <java classname="abc.HelloWorld">
         <classpath>
           <path refid="default.classpath" />
           <path location="lib/*.jar" />
           <path location="build/jar/HelloWorld.jar" />
         </classpath>
       </java>
     </target>
```

Comment: No, that doesn't answer the problem and is actually incorrect in itself as the correct way to configure the target

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).